# Is there a Python function to compute isosurface end-cap geometry like the 'isocaps' function in Matlab?

Tags: python, mayavi, plotly-python, 3d-modelling, isosurface

I want to get some 3D models defined by implicit functions like F(x,y,z)=0.

It can be done using the 'isosurface' and ['isocaps'](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/matlab/ref/isocaps.html?lang=en) functions in MATLAB.

In my case, the constructed models need post-process in Python so it would be better if the modelling can be done in Python.
*'mayavi.mlab.Contour3d'* and *'plotly.graph_objects.Isosurface'* are able to  display the isosurface while *'skimage.measure.marching_cubes'* can be used to extract the trangler mesh.

Can anyone help me find a way in Python to get the isosurface end-cap?

Answer (score -2):

I'm looking for a way to do the exact same thing. Another user gave me the following solution for my own request.

[Is there a way to fill one side of the gyroid surface by using Mayavi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64480835/is-there-a-way-to-fill-one-side-of-the-gyroid-surface-by-using-mayavi)

You have to use an extra tool for visualization to do it. I'm using Mayavi for generating the structures I need but I can't get the surface end-cap by using it.

Maybe the answer to my question can help you out.