# Is there a way to fill one side of the gyroid surface by using Mayavi?

Tags: python, numpy, vtk, mayavi, isosurface

I'm using Mayavi to plot an iso-surface of a gyroid. My problem is that I need a more solid structure by filling one side of the two generated areas.
In the following pictures, you can see how my generated iso-surface looks like and how it should look like after filling one side.

My generated iso-surface:

[image: my generated iso-surface]

How it should look like:

[image: How it should look like]

The iso-surface can be generated by the following equation:

```py
U = sin(2*pi * x/a) * cos(2*pi * y/a) + sin(2*pi * y/a) * cos(2*pi * z/a) \
    + sin(2*pi * z/a) * cos(2*pi * x/a)
```

I plotted the `iso-surface = 0` by using this: `mlab.contour3d(U, contours=[0])`

I hope somebody can help me out.

Comment: I could do it using vedo (https://github.com/marcomusy/vedo), not sure if there an analogous way in mayavi. if interested I can post the solution.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.I'm thankful for any idea of solution. Is there just a plot command using vedo or do you have to solve it in a mathematical way, a boolean operation for example?

Answer (score 1):

Using [`vedo`](https://github.com/marcomusy/vedo):

```py
from vedo import *
import numpy as np

a = 15
pi = np.pi
x, y, z = np.mgrid[:30, :30, :30]/a
U =   sin(2*pi* x) * cos(2*pi* y) + sin(2*pi* y) * cos(2*pi* z) \
    + sin(2*pi* z) * cos(2*pi* x)
iso = Volume(U).isosurface(0)
plane = Grid(sx=29,sy=29, pos=(14.5,14.5,0), resx=200, resy=200)
cpln = plane.cutWithMesh(iso).wireframe(0).c('tomato').lw(0)
show(iso, cpln, axes=1)
```

[image]

(note that the red-tomato "cap" is effectively a different mesh)

PS: you can also use `CubicGrid(n=(29,29,29), spacing=(1,1,1), alpha=1)` (instead of 6 planes). E.g.:

```py
iso = Volume(U).isosurface(0).smoothLaplacian().c('silver').lw(1)
cube = CubicGrid(n=(29,29,29), spacing=(1,1,1))
cube.cutWithMesh(iso).c('silver').alpha(1)
show(iso, cube)
```

[image]

Comment: I hope this will inspire me a little bit to do something similar with Mayavi.

Comment: Since I did not find anything in the documentation: How do I combine `iso` and `cube` and create an STL file from it?

Comment: Try `merge(iso, cube)`.